# SQL Server 2008 R2 not connect to server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed the SQL server 2008 R2 on windows 7, when i want to connect database engine it give the following error message

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>   Cannot connect to (local).
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>   For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

I tried both window and SQL Server authentication but no success.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

First Check whether any SQL Server Instance is running and exists.
You can check list of instances as per below:
Go to command prompt and type in “osql -L” or “sqlcmd -L”.

If instance is showing in list then check your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Start the sqlserver service. Nothing to do in stackoverflow. Move question to serverfault.

Comment: SQL Server services are not running, how to run?